Trouble Replacing Audio in Video File with FFmpeg WASM: File Writing and Unhandled Errors
I'm working on a web project where I need to replace the audio track of a video file with another audio file using FFmpeg WASM. While the equivalent FFmpeg command works fine in a regular command-line environment, I encounter issues when adapting it to FFmpeg WASM.
I've set up a server providing the FFmpeg WASM libraries.
My current task is to replace the audio track in a video file using FFmpeg WASM.
Error Encountered:
While trying to execute the operation, I receive error messages indicating issues with writing the files to FFmpeg WASM memory and another related to TypeError in my JavaScript code.

writing  vid.mp4 REMIX.mp3
classes.js:53  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')
#e.#e.onmessage @ classes.js:53
transcode:66 wrote files
classes.js:53  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')
#e.#e.onmessage @ classes.js:53
transcode:78 Transcoding Process: 6.2548828125 ms
transcode:85  Error during transcoding: ErrnoError: FS error

      const { fetchFile } = FFmpegUtil;
      const { FFmpeg } = FFmpegWASM;
      let ffmpeg = new FFmpeg({ log: true });

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
        const message = document.getElementById('message');
        try {
          await ffmpeg.load({
            coreURL: "{{ url_for('static', filename='ffmpeg/core/dist/umd/ffmpeg-core.js') }}",
          });
          message.textContent = "FFmpeg is ready. Please upload the files.";
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Failed to load FFmpeg:', error);
          message.textContent = "Failed to load FFmpeg core.";
        }
      });

      const videoInput = document.getElementById('uploader-video');
      const audioInput = document.getElementById('uploader-audio');
      const transcodeButton = document.getElementById('transcode-button');

      function updateTranscodeButtonState() {
        if (videoInput.files[0] && audioInput.files[0]) {
          transcodeButton.disabled = false;
        }
      }

      videoInput.addEventListener('change', updateTranscodeButtonState);
      audioInput.addEventListener('change', updateTranscodeButtonState);

      transcodeButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        const message = document.getElementById('message');
        const videoFile = videoInput.files[0];
        const audioFile = audioInput.files[0];

        if (!videoFile || !audioFile) {
          message.textContent = 'Both video and audio files are required!';
          return;
        }

        try {
          
          message.textContent = 'Start transcoding';
          console.log("writing ", videoFile.name, audioFile.name);

          // Here is where I'm trying to write the source files 

          const { videoName } = videoFile;
          ffmpeg.writeFile(videoName, await fetchFile(videoFile));

          const { audioName } = audioFile;
          ffmpeg.writeFile(audioName, await fetchFile(audioFile));

          console.log("wrote files");  

          console.time('Transcoding Process');
          await ffmpeg.exec(
            '-i', videoFile.name,
            '-i', audioFile.name,
            '-map', '0:v',
            '-map', '1:a',
            '-c:v', 'copy',
            '-c:a', 'aac',
            '-strict', 'experimental'
          );
          console.timeEnd('Transcoding Process');

          const data = await ffmpeg.readFile('output.mp4');
          const video = document.getElementById('output-video');
          video.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
          message.textContent = 'Transcoding complete. Video is ready for playback.';
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error during transcoding:', error);
          message.textContent = 'An error occurred during transcoding.';
        }
      });

I believe the errors may relate to how the files are being written to the FFmpeg WASM memory before processing, but I'm not certain. My attempts so far have focused on ensuring that the video and audio files are correctly written into the memory and properly addressed in the transcoding command.
Tried:
Checking the file paths and names being passed to the FFmpeg commands.
Ensuring the asynchronous operations for file writing are completed before transcoding starts.
Could someone help me understand what's going wrong, or suggest a better way to manage files with FFmpeg WASM?
